# How To Start Writing

Tags: creative-writing, plot

I'm new here and have been writing for around two years. I'm still fairly young, and I developed a love of writing around 6th grade. I've gone through many trials and errors, and I have a story I'm currently working on that's a little bit different than the others. I have clear characters and scenes and a general plotline to follow, but the part that always trips me up is *actually* writing. Does anyone have any tips as to where to start out?
Thanks

Comment: Start with this https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/54208/how-to-i-get-motivated-to-start-writing-my-book and https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/47544/what-should-come-first-characters-or-plot or https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/are-there-good-tips-on-being-a-better-creative-writer and see if any of that helps. If not, I'll try to swing by later and get an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look!

Comment: Welcome to Writing SE! Please note that you have to be 13+ to use the site. Thanks for the question.

Comment: @Nai45, Thank you, I am.

Comment: @DWKraus, that first link helped a ton! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing an outline of each chapter and what important events happen in each chapter.   Think about a one to two line blurb over what points you want to hit then.  I modeled my writing a lot on tvshows with season and multi-season long arcs.  I'd also recomend doing your homework about every aspect of the show.  If I was writing military scifi, I'd look at the military units I'm modeling, establish the rank hierarchy, and look at what kind of terms and jargon people in that service might use (Some militaries, like the U.S. military are so large, they have seperate dialects for each service that's based on tons of in jokes).

6th grade is a great age to start... I speak from experience... but don't be dicouraged if you don't have stories.   I started 20 years ago when I was about your age, I'm still not published, I've tossed out two completed manuscripts, and the only character I kept over all this time is a silly ineffective villain who's easy to stick in as he could be a real threat to my heroes, but has a fatal flaw in being increadibly short sighted in planning.  He's good as a first post-origin story starter villain, followed up with a few woefully one sided battles with the hero when I need a quick scrap for the scene.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier with more education and more experience.  Also doing the actual writing will make it easier to do future writing.

There are many sites that give a method to do the writing itself for a story.
I suggest you look at several and see if any of them seem to fit you well.
Snowflake is very good.  A couple of others are slightly better for me. YMMV

If you can take what you have done so far and finish a complete beat sheet then you would be well on your way to writing.  With the beat sheet you have every scene in a logical sequence to follow your plot, and goes through the key gates,  with no holes and no needless detours.

Make sure you have bullet points as phrases that tell who what where when how something happens in each scene.  The why should be implied from those.

Then if you have that just start writing scene 1.  Describe what you see in your head is being done by/to the characters.  Describe the location, motivation, imply the time, and describe the action.  Try to do this by showing what is happening not give a core dump or lecture. Scenes often will be in pairs of the form of action and reaction. So not every scene will have to cover all the 5W2H questions.